# HasMaxLength value increase in entity type configuration not pulling through to migration?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, data-migration

I have an odd one whereby increasing the value of `HasMaxLength` (FYI, from 200 to 500) in an `EntityTypeConfiguration` class seems to have no effect on the next migration that I create. I would have hoped for a modification to the column's data type length obviously.

Having discovered this I have tried adding a `MaxLength` attribute to the related property in my model but this had no impact on the migration created either. In both cases the migration contains empty up and down methods.

Migrations have been working flawlessly up until now. What am I missing?

### Edit

To confirm, if I add an entity then I get a migration as expected with the relevant populated Up and Down methods.

As requested in comments, here is some code:

Configuration constructor:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}
```

DbContext constructor:

```
public ProjectNameContext()
        : base("ProjectName")
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

I'm not going to post the entire config of the startup project (UI) for obvious reasons but the connection string (which is working fine) is as follows:

```
<add name="ProjectName" connectionString="server=.;database=ProjectName;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

### Edit 2

I've been experimenting and tried introducing a `HasColumnName` and the next migration has code for the column rename. If I do a `HasColumnName` and update the `HasMaxLength` then the next migration only has the rename, no change to the length. Very odd!

Comment: Probably in the database, the length has already had 500, make sure that first. What command did you use to generate the migration? Are you using the right context, startup-project, default project in PMC, connection string, etc?

Comment: Database length is unchanged at the original value of 200. Used the usual `Add-Migration "MigrationNameHere" -projectname Data -startupprojectname Ui`. I've typed this so many times and had it work that I've lost count so I don't think it's that?

Comment: Please post the configuration constructor, the dbcontext constructor(s) and the config that belongs to startup project, please use edit button to post the code, not in comment.

Comment: More code added as requested.

Comment: Probably the context ket hasn't been set appropriately in the configuration constructor, go to database execute `select ContextKey from YourDatabase.dbo.__MigrationHistory`, and try put this code `ContextKey = "TheValueYouSeeFromExecutingTheQuery";` configuration's constructor

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the value was `Data.Migrations.Configuration`. It has made no difference though I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the answer to the question is to upgrade Entity Framework from 6.1.0 to 6.1.1. Doing so results in a migration being created that includes the change to the `HasMaxLength` value. It could be a coincidence I guess but its the only change that I can attribute to the migration being created successfully.